# Adding an Opening Pair of Quotes to a Lettrine Letter

Tags: positioning, lettrine

I am using the `\lettrine` package and would like to be able to add opening double quotes to the beginning of a paragraph with a lettrine letter. However, I have not been able to figure out an expedient way of accomplishing this — and putting regular opening quotes in the natural place does not give the desired result as you can see by the following code and output:

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{lettrine}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    
    \input GoudyIn.fd
    \newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
    
    \begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    ``\lettrine[lines=3]{\color{red}\initfamily{T}}{\color{red}\textbf{his}} is one sentence in the paragraph. This is one sentence in the paragraph. This is one sentence in the paragraph. This is one sentence in the paragraph. This is one sentence in the paragraph. This is one sentence in the paragraph. This is one sentence in the paragraph. This is one sentence in the paragraph. This is one sentence in the paragraph. {\textcolor{red}{I would like to add appropriately sized \textit{opening double quotes} to the Lettrine `T'}.} '' 
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Also, adding the double quotes immediately after `\initfamily{` and before the `T` does nothing.

QUESTION: Is there a may to include an appropriately sized opening pair of quotes (red in this case) to the paragraph in an expedient way---without having to resort to producing them elsewhere in the document and then shifting them into position by a set of \hskip(s) and \vskip(s) ?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the `ante=` parameter made for just that purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does that look like what you’re trying to achieve?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    
\input GoudyIn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
    
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\def\frenchquote{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{\Large «\,}}
\def\curlyquote{\Large “\,}
  
\lettrine[ante=\frenchquote, lines=3, findent=.5em, nindent=0em]
{\color{red}\initfamily{T}}{\color{red}\textbf{his}} 
is one sentence in the paragraph. 
This is one sentence in the paragraph. 
This is one sentence in the paragraph. 
This is one sentence in the paragraph. 
This is one sentence in the paragraph. 
This is one sentence in the paragraph. 
This is one sentence in the paragraph. 
This is one sentence in the paragraph. 
This is one sentence in the paragraph.

\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\lettrine[ante=\curlyquote, lines=3, findent=.5em, nindent=0em]
{\color{red}\initfamily{T}}{\color{red}\textbf{his}} 
is one sentence in the paragraph. This is one sentence in the paragraph. 
This is one sentence in the paragraph. 
This is one sentence in the paragraph. 
This is one sentence in the paragraph. 
This is one sentence in the paragraph. 
This is one sentence in the paragraph. 
This is one sentence in the paragraph. 
This is one sentence in the paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Actually, your earlier comment to my question introduced me to something I was not aware of---`ante='; after looking into it further, I found that a combination of that and `lhang=' gave me (after figuring out how they work) mostly what I was looking for. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) I played with it a bit myself, and posting code in a comment is not really viable. Hence, the full-blown answer.